# Python: How to use re.compile after click()

Tags: python, regex

I've successfully coded Python to open a website and then click a link. After that, I'd like to grab info from the site that is "active". But I'm getting the following error:
Search = Regex.search(res.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I think the problem is that I don't know how to "define" the clicked-into webpage as a variable. Here is the code that is relevant:

```
import re, requests, csv, pyperclip, logging
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://espn.go.com/golf/players')
find_player = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Allenby, Robert")
res = find_player.click()
xRegex = re.compile(r'(1991)')
xSearch = xRegex.search(res.text)
output_player_name = xSearch.group(1)
```

This is my first Python coding experience and my first post to ask a question. Thanks in advance for any help.

PS I know that 1991 appears in the webpage. It's the year Robert Allenby turned pro.

Comment: What is return type of `find_player.click()` ?

Comment: The error message occurs because the value of `res` is `None`.  In the problematic line, `res.text` does not work, because there is no attribute `text` to a variable of type `None`.

Comment: find_player.click() finds "Robert Allenby" on the first webpage. Robert Allenby is a hyperlink so click() clicks on that link, bringing up Robert Allenby's profile webpage. That parts actually works (miraculously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find_element_by_partial_link_text() returns a anchor link and click is an event in browser which returns None. To get page content use browser.page_source and process the same as per requirement.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://espn.go.com/golf/players')
href_link = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Allenby")
href_link.click()
res = browser.page_source
print res
xRegex = re.compile(r'(1991)')
xSearch = xRegex.search(res)
output_player_name = xSearch.group(1)
print output_player_name
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Hemraj. I tried the coding you suggested above and it did successfully print res (although I put brackets around res). But I got the following error: xSearch = xRegex.search(res.text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'. Any ideas?

Comment: directly use res , there is no text attribute to res, Updated

Answer (score 0):

`find_player` is of type `WebElement`, res is type `NoneType`.  The clicked-into webpage is held in the variable `browser`.  You can use functions like find_element_by_partial_link_text to find what you need.

By the way, what are you trying to accomplish?  It might help me answer your question better.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to create a database of pro golfers along with some basic data on each -- date of birth, city of birth, year turner pro, etc. I can get all this from espn.com but thought I would use Python to click each name, grab the data, repeat. I haven't tried the loop yet bringing in the names to search from my list as I first want to test it with one golfer (Robert Allenby in this case).

Comment: I tried to change the coding as follows: xSearch = xRegex.search(res.text) replaced by xSearch = xRegex.search(browser.text) but that didn't work either, with error: xSearch = xRegex.search(browser.text)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Is it possible that I have to delay the last bit of coding to wait until the clicked-into page loads? Perhaps the code is running the search for "1991" before the relevant page actually loads? Not sure

Comment: You might try something like `include time`, `time.sleep(1)` to sleep for 1 second and wait for the web page to load.

Comment: Also, you will have to use one of the functions on this page: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html if you are inside a browser window.  I have found `find_element_by_id` and `find_element_by_xpath` to be the most effective in my experience, but you can try others.